# After reboot i've lost all my programs and files

Tags: files, reboot

So I turned off my computer and went shopping and when I came home and turned on my computer everything went as usual but I've lost all my files and programs as if I re-installed Ubuntu. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you shut it down properly, or did you just turn it off?  If you just turned it off, then you probably corrupted your hard disk.

Comment: Looks like it is time for the backups!

Comment: Have you installed (or reinstalled) Ubuntu on that machine more than once, previously? It sounds like you loaded into a different installation. Sometimes MBR gets wiped out and needs to be rebuilt or GRUB needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: Please, post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, `mount` and `df -h`.

Comment: May it be that you accidentally logged in to a guest session?

Comment: Did you change your password during your last session? If so, don't use `sudo passwd your_user_name` to change your password. That breaks an encrypted /home directory, making it look like everything has been deleted. Change your password again using your own login (no **sudo** in front of the **passwd** command), then reboot. Everything should then be back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output of `mount`, i can tell you're running the system from a LiveUSB. This will not save any programs or files you store, and they will disappear when you shut down.

You need to install ubuntu to your hard drive, or to another external drive in order to keep any files or programs. (Ubuntu will also run faster when installed to a hard drive)

You can also set up a persistent thumb drive. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent/ for more information on that.

If you've already installed Ubuntu to your thumb drive, then it seems you've accidentally booted to a thumb drive. Shut down, remove the thumb drive, and turn your computer back on everything should be back to where it was.

Comment: Where is the 'output of mount'? The question poser doesn't seem to have posted it, or has deleted it?

Comment: @Mik: It was posted in a comment... Its gone now though.